# How to create a sql filter that selects a column and returns a distinct on strings with different texts?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select a column and make it distinct on it.

The column is text type.

The problem is that in some rows of this column a string is added beyond the usual value and therefore I cannot filter the data so as to make a distinct.

The column contains the usernames. Example:

column username

```
username1
username2
username3
{hi my name is username2}
username2
{hi my name is username3}
username4
username5
username2
{hi my name is username2}
```

A query that does only one distinct obviously counts me differently each occurrence.

```
select count(distinct username) from table
```

The result I would like to obtain is the count of the distinct usernames: username1; username2; username3; username4; username5

Result: `5`

thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Try doing a regex_substring and then a count distinct.

Comment: _a string is added_, always the same string before? Or is the username always the last word?

Comment: the last is " } " but yes the string before the username is always the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your example reflects your real data, it would be like this:

```
select count(distinct
  replace(
replace(username,’{hi my name is ’,’’),’}’,’’)
 )
from yourtable
```

Option 2:

```
with data as (
  select 'username1' as username union all
  select 'username2' union all
  select 'username3' union all
  select '{hi my name is username2}' union all
  select '{hi my name is username3 and bla bla bla}' union all
  select 'xxxxxxxxxxxx is username6 $$$$$ and bla bla bla}' 
)
select distinct
  substring(
    t1.new_username,
    1,
    case charindex(' ',new_username,0) when 0 then 4000 else charindex(' ',new_username,0) end
    ) as distinct_usernames
from (
  select
    replace(
      substring(
        username,
        charindex('username',username,0),
        4000
      )
     ,'}'
     ,' '
    ) as new_username
  from data
  ) t1
```

Basically this second option uses a subselect to generate a string starting always from username, and replaces the `{` by one space.
With this data, the main query get a substring until the first space is found (bearing in mind if the string doesn't have space, in that case returns 4000 characters - hopefuly you won't have any username that long :) ).

You can test it here ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2f79d5ef8bab475724932fa5c884813))

Comment: Beat me by a minute, but yeah, this should work. Although the last '' is optional, you can call REPLACE with just two arguments, the original string(username) and the string you wish to replace, and if you dont add a third argument, it replaces it with nothing, same as if you replaced it with an empty argument( '')

Comment: thanks and for the " } " it is sufficient to add an additional replace?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works! the problem is that I discovered another problem. The sentence, sometime, has other word after the username. The pattern is always the same.
In summary, possibilities are:
username
hi my name is username
hi my name is username, other words
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add this new case to your question? I don't understand it well from your comment this new case

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it out. If it solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Hi, I tried to test your query but it doesn't work. I think the problem is related to the fact that it can only be used with sql server while I have a db oracle 11g

Comment: Oh yes... the query is built for sql server, everything is standard except the charindex function, you must replace it by instr function for oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564